# CanCan and controllers without models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using CanCan for authorization.  I define the model-action-user rules in /app/config/ability.rb and it's working fine.  I've added the line `load_and_authorize_resource` to my application_controller, and everything's done.

However, I also have numerous views and controllers that don't have a model underneath.  For example, trying to load a statistics page gives

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Statistic):
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
  ...
```

Is there some way for CanCan to work with the controller+action instead of model+action?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `authorize_resource :class => false` in your controller. CanCan will automatically check for abilities on the name of the controller (as a symbol, singular, eg `:statistic` for the `StatisticsController`)

See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers

Comment: If you are using load_and_authorize_resource method, no need to mention class => false.cancan will check and find it out as default.

Comment: @MadhanAyyasamy I dont think so

Comment: @MadhanAyyasamy load_and_authorize_resource breaks if you don't tell it that there's no model for that controller...

Comment: Thank you for this. Couldn't find anything in their documentation that mentions passing the controller as a singular symbol in ability.rb.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Maybe because my controller already was singlular (home).

Comment: What about namespaced controllers? E.g. Users::SessionsController?

Answer (score 5):

You can especify the controller within the `ability.rb` file:

## ability.rb:

```
can :read, StatisticsController # ability.rb
```

## StatisticsController:

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController

  def read
    authorize! :read, current_user 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me but the following did:

```rb
can :read, :statistics # ability.rb
```

Then, in the controller you can either use

```rb
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource class: false
end
```

which will call `authorize! :<action>, :statistics` for you, or you can do it per action explicitly:

```rb
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    authorize! :read, :statistics
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this gem cancacan "https://github.com/piedoom/cancancan" where the persons is finding update the gem cancan to the version of rails new