# Cancan on a no model controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a page with a configuration part where some users can edit element and variable of the site. 
I want to cancan controle the access to the page but as it's not a model, and I'm not sure how to do.

My controller

```
class ConfigurationController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

My menu

```
<% if can?(:read, Configuration) # not sure of that  %> 
    <li><%= link_to t('texts.configuration.title'), configuration_index_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

I have a error with this code :

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Configuration
```

I'm actualy not sure of what mean this error.
What will be the correct way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible follow this post on Github it describe your problem and how to solve it:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/22

and also this:

[CanCan and controllers without models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256969/cancan-and-controllers-without-models)